# Angular Docker compose depending on env

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I want to a `docker-compose` command with argument which indicates which `npm` script should run. For example when I want to build a prod version it should run `npm run build:prod`, when dev `npm run build:dev`.

So I have prepared a `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  customer-support-portal:
    image: "customer-support-portal"
    container_name: "customer-support-portal"
    build: .
    ports:
    - "3000:80"
    volumes:
    - "/usr/src/app/node_modules"
    - ".:/usr/src/app"
```

and `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG env="dev"

### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:${env}

### STAGE 2: Setup ###
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build-step /usr/src/app/dist/customer-support-portal /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

so as you see I tried to somehow set a variable called `env` (default `dev`) which indicates which build should be run. But I want to pass that argument when `docker-compose up -d` is called so it will start app with profile (dev/prod) I want to.

Comment: you can use [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) , its just like using the -e option while running

Comment: One unrelated advice regarding your node build: You should consider making use of the package-lock.json and run `npm ci` instead of `npm install` to make your builds reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass build arguments with the `docker-compose build` command using the `--build-arg` flag. This doesn't seem to be integrated into `docker-compose up --build` though...

`docker-compose build --build-arg=env=prod`

This will be passed into the docker build as you would expect. For this to work as expected (also with the plain `docker build` command) your Dockerfile needs a small modification. The position of the `ARG` instruction is relevant for where the value can be used.

Having `ARG` before `FROM` is not part of the specific build stage and allows passing an argument for the `FROM` instruction. This is commonly used for specifying the version of the base image to be used. If you want to use the arg inside any other instruction, the `ARG` instruction must come after the `FROM`. This however leads to the argument not being usable in the `FROM` instruction - which is fine for your use case.

For details, check [the docker docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) or see [this discussion on github](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31352).

**Example for docker-compose build**

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.12.1
ARG argument="defaultvalue"
RUN echo passed argument \"$argument\"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
    myalpine:
        build: .
```

Command

`docker-compose build --build-arg=argument=compose-cmdline`

Results in

```
Step 3/3 : RUN echo passed argument [$argument]
 ---> Running in 3b58453c3b83
passed argument [compose-cmdline]
```

**Example controlling build arg via environment variable**

You can also make use of the docker-compose file to set build-args from an environment variable instead of the `--build-arg` flag that is only available during `docker-compose build` but not with `docker-compose up`.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
    myalpine:
        build: 
            context: .
            args:   
                argument: $SOMEENV
```

And running it with

`SOMEENV=envarg docker-compose up --build`

This builds your image passing the value of the env var as a build argument during a regular `docker-compose up`. Please be aware that this env variable is also available during container runtime, so you need to make sure not to clash with env vars required during execution.

Comment: So how can I use this `docker-compose` file? I can only build it with those args? So in that case eg. ports are useless becuase then when I'd like to start that container I will have to again provide ports mapping...

Comment: Nope. That's just the smallest working sample showing that build args can be passed via compose and where the `ARG` needs to be put inside the `Dockerfile`. You should be able to integrate those ideas in your own docker-compose so that you only need one single one of them. There might be a solution passing environment variables that could also work during build. I'll extend my answer if that works...

Comment: Doesnt work: 'SOMEENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Yes i ma Using windows

Comment: I'm not sure how passing shell vars works with cmd/powershell, but you could try one `set SOMEENV=envarg` (respectively `set YOUR_NODE_BUILD_ENV=prod`) before and then just running `docker-compose up --build`. I would advice to use a better name than `ENV` for the variable to avoid confusion.