# How to dockerize an Angular app that uses different environments?

Tags: angular, docker

I'm new to Docker, and I'm trying to dockerize an Angular app.
The Angular app has multiple environment configurations that are loaded using `ng build -c=[configration_name]`. Building for production loads `environments.prod.ts`, and building for staging loads `environments.stage.ts`.

To build the docker file, I'm considering approaches A and B below:

(A) If I first build the angular app using `ng build` and then copy the `dist` folder to the docker image - I would have to create multiple images - one for each environment:

Dockerfile for production:

```
#stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN ng build --prod # Loads variables from environments.prod.ts
#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/demo-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Dockerfile for staging:

```
#stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN ng build -c=staging # Loads variables from environments.stage.ts
#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/demo-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

(B) If I first copy only the angular source-code files to the docker image, and then build the angular app - I would have a single image, but then (1) I will have to pass the environment name to the docker file, and (2) I won't be able to know if the build is successful in this line `CMD ["ng", "build", "-c={{environment-name}}"]`, because it would be run by the deployment.

```
#stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install

#stage 2
CMD ["ng", "build", "-c={{environment-name}}"]
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY /app/dist/demo-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Two questions:
(1) What is the right approach to dockerize an Angular app with multiple environments?
(2) How can I pass the environment name to the docker file?

I looked through other questions in SO, the closest one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785285/angular-docker-compose-depending-on-env), but it is not exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not using angular but i can help you with your question, for an express app using typescript i have 3 stages (dev, prod and test), i build dockerfile with 3 stages and in each stage my `NODE_ENV` change:
when i run `docker build --target prod -t me/myimagename .` i'm building an image for production without executing dev and test (builds), but for dev for example when i execute the command that target the dev stage : the prod and dev stage will be executed and for testing i execute the 3 stages.

```
FROM node:17-alpine as prod

ENV NODE_ENV=production

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache tini

COPY package*.json  ./

RUN npm ci  && npm cache clean --force


ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]

COPY . .

CMD [ "node","./dist/index.js" ]

######### developement stage :

FROM prod as dev

RUN apk update && apk add bash

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install --only=development && \
    npm install --global --unsafe-perm typescript && \
    npm install -D typescript &&\
    npm install --global @vercel/ncc && \
    npm install --global nodemon

CMD [ "nodemon","./dist/index.js" ]
######## testing stage

FROM dev as test

ENV NODE_ENV=development

CMD [ "npm","test"]
```

#### for **production** run

`docker build --target prod -t me/myimagename .` .

#### for **dev** run

`docker build --target dev -t me/myimagename .`.

#### for **test stage** run

`docker build --target test -t me/myimagename .`.

Comment: this is how i dockerize my  backend app

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of what you've done, please?